# Which Queries are active on a Derby Database

Tags: derby

Is there a way to find out which Queries are active on a Derby Database
and how long they are running?
Something like Performance Monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several useful performance monitoring features in Derby. See this question for some discussion: [apache derby - explain select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981406/apache-derby-explain-select)